# Compiling Swift source files

Tags: xcode, swift

When I run the Project, Xcode is always show the message "Building AppName | Compiling Swift source files",  without anything. How can I know What wrong with project? thank you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKcrI.png)

Xcode Version：7.1.1（7B1005）

Answer (score 0):

It's because your Xcode has option enabled `Automatically Refresh Views`. To stop that:

1. Open any `XIB` or `Main.StoryBoard` in your project.
2. From the top Menu bar, select Editor > Untick Automatically Refresh Views option.

From now onwards, it will stop refreshing view.

Comment: @KevinCao close the project and start!

Comment: I solved the problem，It' seems to be many optional value in my project. I unpack the value, So It's working now. So strange！Thank you!